# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed:

Tags: openssl, sinatra, foreman

I deployed a Facebook app using Heroku and got it partially working locally. I can see my app but I as soon as I click on connect with Facebook I get an Internal Server Error Message. This is what Foreman is throwing:

> `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed:`

Everything works on Production but I need to get local working to start integrating Mongo and FB.

I followed all the instructions on: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook#working-locally. I created the dev app and modified the .env file accordingly. I created a self-signed certificate but I'm not sure if this is what follows.

I'm on Mac OS 10.8.2 running ruby 1.9.3p194, OpenSSL 1.0.1c, sinatra 1.2.6 and Foreman.

Comment: To anyone running into a similar issue the answer is to tell openssl the path to your certificate. You can find more info here:  
[link](https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/HTTP-Services)  
[link](http://martinottenwaelter.fr/2010/12/ruby19-and-the-ssl-error/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble and solved it

try add the following line into your Gemfile

```
gem 'certified'
```

and execute

```
bundle
```

Run again!