# My app is working locally. It was working 2 weeks ago on Heroku but now I am getting an error. What is wrong here?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

Heroku Log:

```
2018-03-08T00:11:10.222254+00:00 app[web.1]: - F, [2018-03-08T00:11:10.222159 #4] FATAL -- : [ea17d638-5c00-4d47-b3e9-385b4721372e]
2018-03-08T00:11:10.222317+00:00 app[web.1]: - F, [2018-03-08T00:11:10.222237 #4] FATAL -- : [ea17d638-5c00-4d47-b3e9-385b4721372e] OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed):
2018-03-08T00:11:10.222367+00:00 app[web.1]: - F, [2018-03-08T00:11:10.222301 #4] FATAL -- : [ea17d638-5c00-4d47-b3e9-385b4721372e]
2018-03-08T00:11:10.222453+00:00 app[web.1]: - F, [2018-03-08T00:11:10.222373 #4] FATAL -- : [ea17d638-5c00-4d47-b3e9-385b4721372e] app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:10:in `index'
```

Post Controller Index (Line 10 is inside the "else"):

```
  def index
    current_user_ip = remote_ip
    if current_user_ip == 'xx.xx.xx.xxx'
      current_user_coords = [42.4257, -83.0437]
    else
      current_user_coords = Geocoder.coordinates(current_user_ip)
    end

    @posts = Post.near(current_user_coords, 100000, :order => false)
  end
```

Like I said this was functioning perfectly on Heroku recently. Today on github it said to update a gem, so I did that. That's the only change I've made. I'm not sure whether is was broken before the gem update. Any thoughts or more info I can give?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836698/heroku-rails-nethttp-opensslsslsslerror-ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-s

Comment: Have you enabled ssl ? Or is your certificate not valid anymore?

Comment: Or maybe the geocoder need an API key ? I am not familiar with Geocoder, but it uses google right ? Google also has a limit for requests.

Comment: @SimonFranzen how would I find this out about valid certificate?

Comment: @mhkna https://www.google.es/search?q=check+ssl+certificate try one of those free checkers.